# How do I correctly handle a PHP post request?

Tags: php, post, httprequest

I'm making a small API to handle some surveys.

I've the following body:

```
{
  "name":"1: asd",
  
  "children":[
     {
        "name":"2: are",
        "children":[
           {
              "name":"3: wat wat",
              "children":[
                 {
                    "name":"4: in da hut",
                    "context":{
                       "question":"in da hut",
                       "questionType":"rbText",
                       "answers":[
                          {
                             "value":"",
                             "index":0,
                             "indexValue":1
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 },
                 {
                    "name":"5: k k k k",
                    "context":{
                       "question":"k k k k",
                       "questionType":"rbText",
                       "answers":[
                          {
                             "value":"",
                             "index":0,
                             "indexValue":1
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              ],
              "context":{
                 "question":"wat wat",
                 "questionType":"rbMultiple",
                 "answers":[
                    {
                       "value":"sim",
                       "index":2,
                       "indexValue":4
                    },
                    {
                       "value":"nao",
                       "index":3,
                       "indexValue":5
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        ],
        "context":{
           "question":"are",
           "questionType":"rbMultiple",
           "answers":[
              {
                 "value":"potatoes",
                 "index":4,
                 "indexValue":3
              },
              {
                 "value":"nay",
                 "index":4,
                 "indexValue":3
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  ],
  "context":{
     "question":"asd",
     "questionType":"rbText",
     "answers":[
        {
           "value":"",
           "index":5,
           "indexValue":2
        }
     ]
  }
```

}

on the php side, in order to test if the request made it though, I've tried the following:

```
echo $_POST['name'];
```

But I get the following error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: name in
> **C:\xampp\htdocs\LimeAPI\api\objects\create.php** on line
> **15**

So I've added

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

Which prints correctly my request inside an array.

So I've changed my code to iterate over the array and print the element:

```
foreach($_POST as $item) {    
    echo $item;
    var_dump($item);
}
```

But now I'm getting the following:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\LimeAPI\api\objects\create.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br /> Arrayarray(1) {   ["
         {
            "name":"2: are",
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"3: wat wat",
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"4: in da hut",
                        "context":{
                           "question":"in da hut",
                           "questionType":"rbText",
                           "answers":[
                              {
                                 "value":"",
                                 "index":0,
                                 "indexValue":1
                              }
                           "]=>   string(0) "" }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first, to access the whole body of the request:

```
$post_body = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

then, because this returns a string, you need to decode the `JSON`:

```
$content = json_decode($post_body);
```

and then you will have a object representing the request body, which `name` can be retrieved using the arrow operator:

```
echo $content->name
```

Answer (score 1):

From [`$_POST` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) (emphasis mine):

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method **when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` as the HTTP Content-Type** in the request.

Any other MIME type (`application/json`, `application/xml`...) is just not decoded automagically and requires your own parsing.